# Microsoft graph and Azure Ad user authentication

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application registered in Azure ad.

When i do ADAL with the following details i get a authoriazation token to use with microsoft graph api.

```
    `username      = 'admin@domain.com'
    password      = 'password123'
    client_id     = application id from azure ad
    client_secret = keys from application on azure ad
    tenant        = directory id from azure ad`
```

Using this token i can fetch the list of all sites in my sharepoint account.

Below is the endpoint i call to fetch the sites with the bearer token:
        `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*`

But when I just do the client authentication using token generated using below endpoint Iam not able to access the sites list.
        `login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token`

```
    `grant_type : client_credentials
    clientid : client_id
    clientsecrte : client_secret
    scope : https://graph.microsoft.com`
```

It does not return all of the sites.

Is there a way of getting all sites list with just client authentication.

Or can i get a token for user authentication without user password.

Here is the token decoded that i am using:
    `{
       "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
       "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/586145ec-0428-4da6-8061-fb114257ab70/",
       "iat": 1528949458,
       "nbf": 1528949458,
       "exp": 1528953358,
       "aio": "Y2dgYLh*************xAAA=",
       "app_displayname": "App Name",
       "appid": "504ddb16-2899-48be-be57-**********",
       "appidacr": "1",
       "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/586145ec-0428-4da6-8061-fb114257ab70/",
       "oid": "afcf166f-24c2-49f1-b285-b672d0413c50",
       "roles": [
            "Sites.Read.All",
            "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
            "Sites.Manage.All",
            "Sites.FullControl.All",
       ],
       "sub": "afcf166f-24c2-49f1-b285-b672d0413c50",
       "tid": "586145ec-0428-4da6-8061-fb114257ab70",
       "uti": "hwYd8FZCH0KruWGRFiIHAA",
       "ver": "1.0"
      }`

I get other permissions also but these are site related in Microsoft Graph api

Comment: Could you post the error massage you got ? The successful one is using `ROPC` flow and it can get the delegated permissions onbehlaf of the user. But the failed one is using `client_credentials` flow which get the application permissions and cannot onbehlf of the user.

Answer (score 3):

**Cause:**

The successful one is using `ROPC flow` and it can get  **delegated permissions** onbehlaf of the user. But the failed one is using `client_credentials flow` which get  **application permissions** and cannot onbehlf of the user.

---

*Updated Answer*

**Solution:(Before you do this test, ensure you have SPO license in your tenant)**

1. Try to add `Sites.Read.All` Application permission in your registrated AAD Application and **do admin consent** for it before you getting token.
2. If you're using AAD v1 endpoint, you can do admin consent by **clicking Grant permissions button**.If you're using v2 endpoint, please input this kind of URL in your internet browser to do admin grant:

   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourtenant}/adminconsent?client_id={the applicationid of your client}&state=123&redirect_uri={the redirect uri of your app}`

and sign in with Global admin account and accept this permission.

[image]

3. In my test lab, I used v2 endpoint.Here is the token I got via Postman:
   [image]

Here is decoded token in https://jwt.ms , we can decoded the token to ensure it has the permissions we want.

[image]

4. Then I use this token in the head to call Microsoft Graph API and succeeded:

[image]

For more detials about Site permission for Microsoft Graph, please refer to [this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#sites-permissions).

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: I have Sites.Read.All permission granted. I do not get any error while using the client_credentials flow but do not get the list of all sites in the sharepoint account. It just sends me the subsites of the main tenant site.Please can you help me out here.

In azure ad account i have granted all the permissions application and delegated to the app.

Comment: @SurajShelke - I have the exact same issue.   Using the app only authentication, not all sites are returned when using the  sites/search api call of graph.

Comment: Hi @SurajShelke, I will do a deep test for this issue and keep you updated.

Comment: Hey thanks @WayneYang-MSFT looking forward to hear from you.

ruelloehr if you are alright with user to login before the site query or can take password from user then you can use the grant_type as password which works fine.

Comment: Hi @SurajShelke , I have updated my answer. In my test lab, I use v2 endpoint to do this but its result should be same as v1 endpoint. I can list the sites in my tenant. You can check this answer to see if it is helpful to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, one last question where can get the SPO license for azure. I have the Office 365 Business Premium enabled and assinged.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT In the Office 365 license i have the Sharepoint online (Plan 1) active

Comment: @SurajShelke , That looks fine, could you decode your token to check if there is `Sites.Read.All` permission in the token?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT
Yes i have the permission listed but not bale to get the complete site:
"roles": [
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Manage.All",
    "Sites.FullControl.All",
  ]

Comment: @SurajShelke . That's weird, Though I have the SPO Plan 2 license, but SPO plan 1 should work. I will escalate this case and keep you updated.

Comment: @SurajShelke I have reported this. I will keep updated once it have any process.

Comment: Hi @SurajShelke , Can you tell me the details about how do you approach this?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT
 I follow the exact same steps that you gave above.
I have an app installed in Azure AD with all graph api application and delegated permissions. I use v1 endpoint so grant those permission through Grant Permission option in the Azure portal and then get the token with grant_type as client_credentials.Then i use the the above site search api to get the site list.I have SPO Pack.

Comment: Hi @SurajShelke . Could you use Fiddler to catch the traffic and log so that we can do troubleshoot further.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT As I'm having the same issue, I'm happy to help with this.  I've also been in talks with Brad Cleaver from Microsoft about this issue.    What data would best help you?   Our reproduction scenario so far has been to use the graph api with an app only auth token and then compare those results to those we get by logging into the graph sandbox and running the same call.

Comment: Hi @ruelloehr . Thanks for your help. If we can catch the token and decode it, it may be the most helpful data.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT : I have added the decoded token into the ticket if that might help.I was not able to get the fiddler logs yesterday, hopefully today i will update those.

Comment: @SurajShelke , Thanks for your update. I have checked it and the token should be fine.

Comment: Hi @WayneYang-MSFT can I ask what could be the possible problem and which side has this limitation is it Microsoft Graph Api or Azure AD.

Comment: @SurajShelke , I'm not sure. But I think it should be one issue about AAD or graph API. Maybe you can open one support ticket to call Microsoft Support Team to resolve this. But I will also keep following this issue.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT - I did some more searching on my end.   At this point - i think the graph api just doesn't work site discovery.    To prove this - i make a call to the graph api /sites?search=* call.  I get 2 results.     I then make the call:  https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web IsContainer:true'&selectproperties='SiteId, WebId, UniqueId, Path, Title'&trimduplicates=true    and get around 75 different sites.

Comment: Hi @SurajShelke , I have done some test and but still cannot reproduce your issue. Sorry for that . Maybe you can open one support ticket on Azure portal to contact Microsoft support Team for more effecient solution.;-)

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT, just had one more issue, with the token generated for sharepoint i am able to fetch the OneDrive drives also. Is there a way to restrict the token only for Sharepoint sites and not OneDrive....will really appreciate your swift reply on this one.