# SharePoint + Azure AD + Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have registered an app in Azure AD portal and given Microsoft Graph API permissions to the app to read all sites.

I generate a access token using v2.0 endpoint. With the token i can access the sharepoint site collections which is fine. But using same token i am to access the onedrive also.

Is there a way to just access the sharepoint and not onedrive? Are there any permissions in Graph api or Azure ad portal to restrict this access for the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph API provides access to data in Office 365 (like calendars and messages from Exchange, sites and lists from SharePoint, documents from OneDrive, notebooks from OneNote, tasks from Planner, workbooks from Excel, etc.), as well as users and groups from Azure AD and other data objects from more Microsoft cloud services.

> Is there a way to just access the sharepoint and not onedrive?

Navigate to your App in AAD, go to the `Microsoft Graph` in `Required permissions`. Just do not choose the options of onedrive.

For more details about permissions of onedrive, refer to `Display String` in this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#files-permissions). Then if you get the token by the App, it will not be able to access onedrive.

Comment: hi @Joy Wang, thans for the reply, i have just selected the Sharepoint application permission as Read items in all site collections (preview) which is Sites.Read.All permission but still i am able to access OneDrive.No OneDrive related permission selected. I think Graph has same permission that can access both sharepoint and onedrive, but i am not able to differentiate them

Comment: @SurajShelke From the official docs, `Sites.Read.All : Allows the app to read documents and list items in all site collections without a signed in user.` `Files.Read.All : Allows the app to read all files in all site collections without a signed in user.` Is it possible some sharepoint files were stored in onedrive?

Comment: I do not think that, because i have separated folders and files created for each. Does Sharepoint uses Onedrive internally to store the data?

Comment: @SurajShelke Seems find the reason, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/index#2-make-calls-to-a-resource), as it mentioned, `Once your app is authorized and received an access token, it can make requests to the Microsoft Graph endpoint for OneDrive or SharePoint resources. ` The api is also for sharepoint and onedrive.

Comment: hey @Joy thanks for the exact link, i guess now i can confirm and find some other apis to access Sharepoint other than Graph

Comment: hey Joy please can you look into this issue if you have some ideas - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699284/microsoft-graph-and-azure-ad-user-authentication

Comment: @SurajShelke I will look into it tomorrow.